# Azure Mongo Cosmos Ping Test Equivalent

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to do a Ping Like Operation on a Cosmos/Mongo/DocumentDB in Azure.

The Collection Has Zero Documents in it.

I am Using the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.dll)

I want to do something that would exercise a full round trip and auth cycle to the Cosmos DB to prove the general integrity of the config before any documents are in the collection.

I was looking for an operation on **DocumentClient** that would prove or disprove all the configuration is correct at runtime, like a Ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `_client.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)`, which will validate your configuration and throw if there are any exceptions connecting to the database.

In fact, it is recommended that you call this on service/app startup to avoid latency on your first request.

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.openasync?view=azure-dotnet
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips

Comment: It's worth noting that this method doesn't exist in the .NET Standard version of the library.

Comment: This Lead to me stumbling onto ReadDocumentCollectionAsync also.  With that I can log the property AltLink which lets me log and confirm the actual connected collection that is being used at run time.